# How do I perform a GET request on a query string?

Tags: javascript, express, knex.js

I have a restaurant reservations project that when you type in a query string, for example: `http://localhost:5000/reservations?2020-12-31` it will return with the given reservations on that day.

I am using Knex to perform my queries and I have the first function which will return all reservations from the database:

```
const listReservations = () => knex('reservations').select('*');
```

Then I am trying to take these, and return the specified reservations:

```
const list = async (req, res) => {
  const response = await service.listReservations();
  const data = response.filter((reserve) => {
    return Date.parse(reserve.reservation_date) - Date.now() > 0;
  });
  console.log(data);
  res.json({ data });
};
```

The data looks like:

```
[
  {
    "first_name": "Rick",
    "last_name": "Sanchez",
    "mobile_number": "202-555-0164",
    "reservation_date": "2020-12-31",
    "reservation_time": "20:00:00",
    "people": 6,
    "created_at": "2020-12-10T08:30:32.326Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-12-10T08:30:32.326Z"
  },
  {
    "first_name": "Frank",
    "last_name": "Palicky",
    "mobile_number": "202-555-0153",
    "reservation_date": "2020-12-30",
    "reservation_time": "20:00",
    "people": 1,
    "created_at": "2020-12-10T08:31:32.326Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-12-10T08:31:32.326Z"
  },
  {
    "first_name": "Bird",
    "last_name": "Person",
    "mobile_number": "808-555-0141",
    "reservation_date": "2020-12-30",
    "reservation_time": "18:00",
    "people": 1,
    "created_at": "2020-12-10T08:31:32.326Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-12-10T08:31:32.326Z"
  },
  {
    "first_name": "Tiger",
    "last_name": "Lion",
    "mobile_number": "808-555-0140",
    "reservation_date": "2025-12-30",
    "reservation_time": "18:00",
    "people": 3,
    "created_at": "2020-12-10T08:31:32.326Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-12-10T08:31:32.326Z"
  },
  {
    "first_name": "Anthony",
    "last_name": "Charboneau",
    "mobile_number": "620-646-8897",
    "reservation_date": "2026-12-30",
    "reservation_time": "18:00",
    "people": 2,
    "created_at": "2020-12-10T08:31:32.326Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-12-10T08:31:32.326Z"
  }
]
```

If I parse my date, subtract today's date and return the dates above 0, I get: Tiger and Anthony. If I return the ones below 0 I get the first three names.

The test case is passing in 2020-12-31 as a query string and is expecting Rick. How do I perform a GET request of the given query strings?

Comment: You should also look into adding a `where` clause to your sql query using `.where('reservation_date', '>', new Date())`, instead of doing `filter()` on the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Express, you can use `req.query` to access the query parameters of the url (everything after the `?`). But this will only work if your query string is formatted correctly. It needs to have formatting like this: `?field=value&foo=bar&date=2020-12-31`.

Once you have a url with a query formatted this way, Express can parse it and you can use it like this:

```
knex('reservations').where({ 'reservation_date': req.query.date })
```

That is the recommended solution (plus some parameterization refactoring that I leave as an exercise for the reader). But if changing the format of the query string is not an option, then you could instead do some string processing on `req.originalUrl`, like this:

```
const indexOfQs = req.originalUrl.indexOf('?')
const date = indexOfQs === -1 ? null : req.originalUrl.substr(indexOfQs + 1)
knex('reservations').where({ 'reservation_date': date })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query: `knex('reservations').where({'reservation_date':'2020-12-31'})`. Refer [knex documentation](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-where) for more information.

Comment: So I've implemented that, and also changed the filter method in my controller list function to: `const data = response.filter((reserve) => {
    return Date.parse(reserve.reservation_date);
  });` which gets the test to pass but now it's hard coded so even when there's no query string I only get that one reservation.

Comment: This one I have given for eg. You would need to get the date from request query in get method handler, and send that to knex.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Knex, to avoid unnecessarily loading all the records and filtering on the client I find Wazeed's answer to be the right one, but if you try to filter you can simply filter by the reservation_date string. Please try the following example

By the way in the example you share I don't see where you take the value of the query string in this case 2020-12-31

```js
const data = [
  {
    "first_name": "Rick",
    "last_name": "Sanchez",
    "mobile_number": "202-555-0164",
    "reservation_date": "2020-12-31",
    "reservation_time": "20:00:00",
    "people": 6,
    "created_at": "2020-12-10T08:30:32.326Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-12-10T08:30:32.326Z"
  },
  {
    "first_name": "Frank",
    "last_name": "Palicky",
    "mobile_number": "202-555-0153",
    "reservation_date": "2020-12-30",
    "reservation_time": "20:00",
    "people": 1,
    "created_at": "2020-12-10T08:31:32.326Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-12-10T08:31:32.326Z"
  },
  {
    "first_name": "Bird",
    "last_name": "Person",
    "mobile_number": "808-555-0141",
    "reservation_date": "2020-12-30",
    "reservation_time": "18:00",
    "people": 1,
    "created_at": "2020-12-10T08:31:32.326Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-12-10T08:31:32.326Z"
  },
  {
    "first_name": "Tiger",
    "last_name": "Lion",
    "mobile_number": "808-555-0140",
    "reservation_date": "2025-12-30",
    "reservation_time": "18:00",
    "people": 3,
    "created_at": "2020-12-10T08:31:32.326Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-12-10T08:31:32.326Z"
  },
  {
    "first_name": "Anthony",
    "last_name": "Charboneau",
    "mobile_number": "620-646-8897",
    "reservation_date": "2026-12-30",
    "reservation_time": "18:00",
    "people": 2,
    "created_at": "2020-12-10T08:31:32.326Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-12-10T08:31:32.326Z"
  }
];

const output = data.filter(value => value.reservation_date === "2020-12-31");

console.log(output)
```